# compound maths in php wrong, losing 3.00

Tags: php, variables, math, equation-solving

I have got a calculation written in php, its meant to calculate the total balance **(echo $vf;)** after 3 months.

The answer I get is *603.00*

The answer I should get is *606.02*

Somewhere I have gone wrong that it is losing 3 the math, any idea ?

I have been working on this for weeks and am so close, any help will be very much appreciated.

**Code**

```
$p = 0;
$i = 0.06;
$c = 12;
$n = 3/12;
$r = 200;

$x = $i / $c;
$y = pow((1 + $x), ($n * $c));

$vf = $p * $y + ($r * ($y - 1) / $x); 
echo $vf;
```

Sand box if needed https://3v4l.org/FigRr

Thanks

**UPDATE**

have been informed my math may be wrong, here is the original formula bellow, can anyone see how I have written the php wrong ?

[image]

**UPDATE**

What I am after is to get the compound of 200 after 3 months, when I have used online calculators I get 606.
for example http://www.thecalculatorsite.com/finance/calculators/compoundinterestcalculator.php

**Update**
have tried:

```
$i = 0.06;
$c = 12;
$n = 3;
$r = 200;

    $x = $i / $c;
    $z = $n / 12;
    $y = pow((1 + $x), ($z * $c));

    $vf =  $y + ($r * ($y - 1) / $x);

     echo $vf;
```

has improved the answer and am getting 604, but still not getting the 606

Comment: Did the math manually and got 603.005

Comment: Hmm ok, I will add the formula im trying to convert to PHP to see if the math i have written is wrong

Comment: there seem to be some inconsistencies with the naming of your variables n and z but it looks to me like you've converted the formula to php properly.

Comment: I have changed the php a bit, il revert to my original code for you. 2 mins

Comment: Are your values correct? I tried solving the formula by hand and I get 603.005

Comment: @Rhopercy the formula in php or the image formula ?

Comment: @Rhopercy hmm, when I enter the variables into this calculator it seems to give 606 http://www.thecalculatorsite.com/finance/calculators/compoundinterestcalculator.php

Comment: Now I understand, php is making $p*$y=0*$y which is equal 0, assuming that values outside the ((1+i/c)^n*c) are ignored the result is aproximating to 605

Answer (score 0):

php is making $p*$y=0*$y which is equal 0, assuming that values outside the ((1+i/c)^n*c) are ignored the result is aproximating to 605

You should make an ifclause to evaluate $p!=0 kinda like this

```
if($p!=0)
{
//regular formula
$FV = ($p(1+($i/$c)^($n*$c))) + ($R((1+($i/$c)^($n*$c)-1)*($i/$c)))
}else{
//normal formula without $p
$FV = (1+($i/$c)^($n*$c)) + ($R((1+($i/$c)^($n*$c)-1)*($i/$c)))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

 $p = 200; // Starting amount
    $i = 0.05; // Interest rate
    $c = 12; // compound frequency set to monthly
    $n = 3/12; // Current time invested set to 6 months
    $r = 200; // Monthly investment is 200

    $x = $i / $c;
    $y = pow((1 + $x), ($n * $c));

     $vf = $p * $y + ($r * (1 + $x) * ($y - 1) / $x);



    echo $vf;
```